# SQL Prevent Duplicate Records from being added

Tags: sql, ms-access

What do I need to add to this SQL Statement to say if the ProductionOrderNo in 
SPECIALS_Output already exists the do not add the record from TEMP_Specials? The ProductionOrderNo in SPECIALS_Output is already a PrimaryKey.

```
strSqlAddTempSpecials = "INSERT INTO SPECIALS_Output ( ProductionOrderNo, ItemNo, Description, ExtraDescription, Quantity, ItemWeight, CreationDate, DueDate, StartingDate, Length ) " & _
"SELECT TEMP_Specials.ProductionOrderNo, TEMP_Specials.ItemNo, TEMP_Specials.Description, TEMP_Specials.ExtraDescription, TEMP_Specials.Quantity, TEMP_Specials.ItemWeight, TEMP_Specials.CreationDate, TEMP_Specials.DueDate, TEMP_Specials.StartingDate, LintelInfo.Length " & _
"FROM TEMP_Specials LEFT JOIN LintelInfo ON TEMP_Specials.ItemNo = LintelInfo.[No] " & _
"WHERE (((LintelInfo.ItemType)<>" & Chr(34) & "Brick" & Chr(34) & " And (LintelInfo.ItemType)<>" & Chr(34) & "#N/A" & Chr(34) & " And (LintelInfo.ItemType)<>" & Chr(34) & "Windpost Kit" & Chr(34) & ") AND ((TEMP_Specials.Status)=" & Chr(34) & "Finished" & Chr(34) & "));"
```

Comment: Evidently the record you are adding has no candidate key value that conflicts with any candidate key value in the target fable. You need to track that down.

Answer (score 0):

you can create **unique index** on `ProductionOrderNo`

Open the table in design view in MS Access, select the `ProductionOrderNo`, and under properties (General) select `Indexed: yes (No Duplicates)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution would to add a condition to the query that filters our records that belong to a ProductionOrderNo that already exist in the target table.

This could be done with a LEFT JOIN combined with WHERE ... IS NULL, or with a NOT EXISTS condition on a correlated subquery.

Here is a solution with LEFT JOIN :

```
strSqlAddTempSpecials = 
    "INSERT INTO SPECIALS_Output ( ProductionOrderNo, ItemNo, Description, ExtraDescription, Quantity, ItemWeight, CreationDate, DueDate, StartingDate, Length ) " & _
"SELECT TEMP_Specials.ProductionOrderNo, TEMP_Specials.ItemNo, TEMP_Specials.Description, TEMP_Specials.ExtraDescription, TEMP_Specials.Quantity, TEMP_Specials.ItemWeight, TEMP_Specials.CreationDate, TEMP_Specials.DueDate, TEMP_Specials.StartingDate, LintelInfo.Length " & _
"FROM TEMP_Specials LEFT JOIN LintelInfo ON TEMP_Specials.ItemNo = LintelInfo.[No] " & _
"LEFT JOIN SPECIALS_Output ON SPECIALS_Output.ProductionOrderNo = TEMP_Specials.ProductionOrderNo " & _
"WHERE ((SPECIALS_Output.ProductionOrderNo IS NULL) AND ((LintelInfo.ItemType)<>" & Chr(34) & "Brick" & Chr(34) & " And (LintelInfo.ItemType)<>" & Chr(34) & "#N/A" & Chr(34) & " And (LintelInfo.ItemType)<>" & Chr(34) & "Windpost Kit" & Chr(34) & ") AND ((TEMP_Specials.Status)=" & Chr(34) & "Finished" & Chr(34) & "));"
```

This will insert new records while ignoring duplicates, unlike the unique index approach, which will reject all records as soon as at least on duplicate exists.